# GitVersion: How do you increment the version of master branch after a pull request from release?

Tags: git, version-control, continuous-deployment, git-flow, gitversion

I am running GitVersion with GitFlow in Continuous Deployment mode with practically all default settings.

This is my GitVersion.yaml:

```
mode: ContinuousDeployment
continuous-delivery-fallback-tag: ''
branches: 
  master:
    tracks-release-branches: true
merge-message-formats: {}
ignore:
  sha: []
```

These are the steps I am taking:

1. Create tag named `1.0.0` on the `master` branch
2. Create the `develop` branch off of master (GitVersion shows this as 1.1.0, **which is great**, this is what I want)
3. Create the `feature/myfeature` branch off of `develop`
4. Create a commit to `feature/myfeature`
5. Pull request from `feature/myfeature -> develop`
6. At this point we are at `1.1.0`, and this makes complete sense to me.
7. Create the `release` branch off of `develop`
8. If I run GitVersion, I am still at `1.1.0`, again, this makes sense to me.
9. Pull request from `release -> master`
10. Master now shows the version is `1.0.1`. **Why is GitVersion not recognizing the history that I just pulled from the `release` branch?**

The only thing that I can do to solve the issue is to manually generate a tag on my release branch, which GitVersion will then use to determine the next version. I do not want to create the tag until I pull into master, at which point I will generate a new build and set a tag on my master branch automatically via my pipelines in Azure.

Comment: i'm having the same issue here. i think it's expecting the release branch to have the version number in it, but that isn't our convention

Comment: I got the exact same problem. Have you guys found a solution?Even using the version number in the name of the release branch (e.g. `release/1.1.0`) does not help because the merge message when using a pull request is different than when you would do a normal merge. I tried it with a normal merge (no PR) and that would work.